# Logging for multiple OSGi bundles working together

Tags: java, logging, osgi, slf4j

Working on an application which involves multiple OSGi bundles. SLF4j is the underlying logging framework. Do I need to configure the `logger.properties` separately for each bundle or is there any specific logging approach used for OSGi bundles?

In former case, what will happen to the sequence of logging for each bundle into the file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use Apache Sling's *org.apache.sling.commons.log* bundle, which provides an SLF4j implementation that plays well with OSGi. See http://sling.apache.org/site/logging.html , downloads from http://sling.apache.org/site/downloads.cgi or from Maven Central.